# Axios onDownload event total is 0 , also responseHeader['content-length'] is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, progress-bar

```js
const DownloadFile  = async (params) => {
    return await axios.get<string>(`${}/url`, {
        params: {
            params: params,
        },
        onDownloadProgress(progressEvent) {
        var percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100)/progressEvent.total)
            console.log(percentCompleted )    // gets infinte as progressEvent.total is 0
        },
    })
    .then(res => {
        return res.data;
    });
};
```

I am trying to show the progress barin reactjs using `onDownloadprogress` event, but the total value is coming as `0` when I check in console. Also there is no `responseHeader[content-length]` to use.  Is there any other way to get the percentage?

Here `progressevent.total` is coming as zero and hence results in `infinity`